# The DJI Onboardsdk cannot take off automatically

Tags: dji-sdk

- I have some questions that I need help with!!

I'm a beginner to the Onboardsdk and I'm using the main controller of N3.
I downloaded the SDK for stm32 from your documentation and ran it.

- I want automatic take-off and I follow your official manual implementation steps.
- I've tried the following steps:
- Initialize -> Activate -> Obtain Control -> Arm -> Auto take off
- Initialize -> Activate -> Obtain Control -> Auto take off -> Arm

But I couldn't take off in the simulator and the first time I executed the arm command, the motor turned a little bit but stopped very quickly,
and then the arm command and disarm command could no longer be implemented.
Please help me, I really need your help

Answer (score 0):

When you first use the OSDK you need to be connected to the internet and have your RC connected to a mobile device running DJI GO. Have you done this step?